# Background extern svg

Tags: svg

I want to apply a background to the outside of the heart shape in svg and I want the inside of the heart to remain transparent, is this possible? thank you in advance

[image]

Here is the SVG code :

```
<svg width="23" height="23" viewBox="0 0 23 21" fill="none" class="card__icone__default" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path d="M20.3647 1.43666C18.01 -0.752399 14.5081 -0.358649 12.3468 2.07416L11.5003 3.02573L10.6538 2.07416C8.49677 -0.358649 4.99052 -0.752399 2.63583 1.43666C-0.0626076 3.94916 -0.204405 8.45854 2.21044 11.182L10.5249 20.5476C11.062 21.1523 11.9343 21.1523 12.4714 20.5476L20.7858 11.182C23.205 8.45854 23.0632 3.94916 20.3647 1.43666Z" stroke="#101010"/>
</svg>
```

I want to apply a background to the outside of the heart and transparent to the inside of the heart

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I have difficulty understanding, can you be more specific please?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it for `<img src=""` because global CSS can not style the *inside* of images.

Alternative is to load your SVG yourself, and inject it into the DOM, that way CSS can be applied

```html
<script src="https://load-file.github.io/element.js"></script>

<load-file src="https://svg-cdn.github.io/heart.svg">
  <style shadowRoot>
    svg {
      background: gold;
      width: 160px
    }
    
    path {
      fill: green
    }
  </style>
</load-file>

<style>
  svg {
    background: pink;
    width: 150px
  }
  
  path {
    fill: gold
  }
</style>
<load-file replaceWith src="https://svg-cdn.github.io/simpleheart.svg">
  </load-file
```

I wrote a Dev.to post about the `<load-file>` Web Component:  https://dev.to/dannyengelman/load-file-web-component-add-external-content-to-the-dom-1nd

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but is it not possible to modify the <svg> code directly?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the path for masking off the inner part of the path and then apply the mask to a rectangle. The white area of the mask will be transparent, whereas the black part (the path) will be masked off.

```html
<svg width="300" viewBox="0 0 24 23" fill="none" stroke-linejoin="arcs">
  <defs>
    <path id="p1" d="M 20.86 2.44 C 18.51 0.25 15.01 0.64 12.85 3.07
    L 12 4.02 L 11.15 3.07 C 9 0.64 5.49 0.25 3.14 2.44
    C 0.44 4.95 0.3 9.46 2.71 12.18 L 11.03 21.55
    C 11.56 22.15 12.43 22.15 12.97 21.55 L 21.29 12.18
    C 23.71 9.46 23.56 4.95 20.86 2.44 Z" />
    <mask id="m1">
      <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white" />
      <use href="#p1" fill="black"/>
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="silver" mask="url(#m1)"/>
  <use href="#p1" stroke="#101010" stroke-width="2" />
</svg>
```